# Resize an add-on's sidebar for ease-of-use

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-apps-script-addon

I am trying to implement interactive pages with Google Apps Script. I've successfully opened a document in the UI sidebar, but the dimensions of the sidebar make it difficult to use:

How can the embedded sidebar page be made more attractive / easier to use?

My Google doc is here : https://docs.google.com/document/d/17AtHwUSQdci-lh7BDvXeELcpZdXr27AryHlfagRR4Hg/edit

[image]
Gode.gs

```js
      var TITLE = 'Sidebar Title';


      //Here is the code.gs code:
      function onOpen() {
        var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
        ui.createMenu('==Sidebar==')
        .addItem('Show Document','SideBar3')
        .addToUi();
      };

      function SideBar3()
      {
        var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ModeLessDialog').setTitle('Handler Communications');
         ui.setWidth(800)

        DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
      }
```

```html
 //Here is the HTML file.  I called it ModeLessDialog.html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
      </head>
      <body>
      <iframe  src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yb7knN941rdS-6okHQu_ZkvkgIaqXUIMioSAru9fzK4/" height="1000" width="90%"></iframe>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can no longer change the sidebar width in Google addons. The UI had the setWidth() method earlier but it is now deprecated.

> In Google Docs and Forms, sidebars now ignore the setWidth() method; they cannot be changed from the default width of 300px.

See [release notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2014#february_2014) mentioning this change.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer I know about that ; but there are others ways to eg: fix the scroll option ; make the iframe resizable ; iframe could be responsive  but I don't know exactly how it works.